# cost of casting array to array in php

Tags: php

I have some bad programming habits caused by ocd, but let's not discuss my obsessive compulsive disorder while programming (although this post reinforces it, omg).

I have these two pieces of code (time to execute 2.1934509277344E-5):

```
    function get_paths($string, $array) {

        $result = array();

        foreach($array as $i)
            if (stripos($i, $string) !== false)
                $result[] = $i;

        return empty($result) ? false : $result;

    }
```

The return statement looks inverted, with the negative result coming first (my formalist folks would go crazy). I know, I know, I could add a negation, but it looks worst. To avoid this I came up with the following solution (time to execute 2.288818359375E-5):

```
    function get_paths($string, $array) {

        $result = null;

        foreach($array as $i)
            if (stripos($i, $string) !== false)
                (array)$result[] = $i;

        return isset($result) ? $result : false;

    }
```

This piece of code involves the cast `(array)$result[] = $i;`. The point is: how dumb is it to cast an array to an array everytime? **Do someone have some in depth information about casting to the same type in php?**

Comment: it is dumb in the sense that you're basically just saying "This apple is an apple" over and over and over again.

Comment: but is it an tautology (in processing terms)?

Comment: it's useless busywork. define it as an array to begin with, then count how many elements are in it after the loop finishes. isset() is rather pointless in this case.

Comment: you missed the point completely dude. this is not what i'm asking.

Comment: I'm not missing. I'm saying that it's pointless to worry about this. If you really want to find out, benchmark both versions and see which one is slower.

Comment: sorry, but yes you are ;)

Comment: @lolol It's an implementation detail, it only matters to "you", no one outside of this function will care, least of all the PHP compiler :S, Now go see a therapist.

Comment: @Flosculus thank you, very useful information. :)

Comment: Hey folks, my english is bad, also my love for books forces me to be wordy sometimes. sorry about that. I bolded the question to clarify.

Comment: Any additional code you make naturally has a detrimental effect to its performance. what makes your question so confusing is that you're trying to improve its style while reducing performance, when ironically it actually makes it harder to read.

Comment: what I'm trying to do is observe, fool around a little, produce something and learn with this beautiful world around me through questions that for some reason get my interest, like this one: how the php compiler deals with casting an object to the same type. is it a true tautology? :)

Comment: ... I don't care anymore

Comment: looks like you never did ;)

Answer (score 0):

If it matters so much to you:

```
function get_paths($string, $array) {

    $result = array();

    foreach($array as $i)
        if (stripos($i, $string) !== false)
            $result[] = $i;

    return count($result) > 0 ? $result : false;

}
```